# Problem writing unicode utf-8 data to file in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm having some issues writing unicode to a file in my Python program.

Here is the code that 'saves' the file:

```
def file_save(self):
    # save changes to existing file
    if self.filename and isfile(self.filename):

        self.watcher.removePath(self.filename)
        s = codecs.open(self.filename,'w','utf-8')
        s.write(unicode(self.ui.editor_window.toPlainText()))
        s.close()
        self.ui.button_save.setEnabled(False)
        self.watcher.addPath(self.filename)
    # save a new file
    else:
        fd = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
        newfile = fd.getSaveFileName()
        if newfile:
            s = codecs.open(newfile,'w','utf-8')
            s.write(unicode(self.ui.editor_window.toPlainText()))
            s.close()
            self.ui.button_save.setEnabled(False)
```

Once that method is called I receive this error message:

```
line 113, in file_save
s.write(unicode(self.ui.editor_window.toPlainText()))
NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined
```

I am running Python 3.2 and can't seem to find the issue anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Unicode support was "fixed" in 3.x. Normal string literals are stored as Unicode, and the normal `open()` function has gained an `encoding` argument thereby making `codecs.open()` obsolete.

```
    s = open(self.filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    s.write(self.ui.editor_window.toPlainText())
```